# PHP Echo users from login table into a select menu and then

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to echo all full names from my login table to a select menu. Once a user selects a name, i want it to pull the email address for that user from the login table and place it into an input field. When i try this, its telling me the variable is undefined.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="rep" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Change Rep</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select class="form-control" id="rep" name="rep">
                    <option value=""></option>


    <?php include_once( "connection.php"); $result=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM login  "); 
                    while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $res['name']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $res[ 'name']; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
            <label for="reassignmentemail" class="col-sm-3 control-label">reassignmentemail</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reassignmentemail" name="reassignmentemail">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now the ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE THE SCRIPT */
                $("#rep").change(function(){ /* WHEN YOU CHANGE AND SELECT FROM THE SELECT FIELD */
                  var rep = $(this).val(); /* GET THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED DATA */
                  var dataString = "rep="+rep; /* STORE THAT TO A DATA STRING */

                  $.ajax({ /* THEN THE AJAX CALL */
                    type: "POST", /* TYPE OF METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
                    url: "get-data.php", /* PAGE WHERE WE WILL PASS THE DATA */
                    data: dataString, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING */
                    success: function(result){ /* GET THE TO BE RETURNED DATA */
                      $("#reassignmentemail").val(result); /* THE RETURNED DATA WILL BE SHOWN IN THIS DIV */
                    }
                  });

                });
              });
            </script>
```

the get-data.php file

```
   <?php

            if(!empty($_POST["rep"])){
            $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'blog');


            $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT* FROM login WHERE name='$rep' ");
            if($result){
              $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
              echo $data[4];
            }


            }
            ?>
```

its telling me that the $rep variable is not defined, any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: your code is vulnerable please filter variable and do validation before use in query or use prepare statement**

define variable before use it  `$rep = $_POST["rep"];`

**Example -**

```
 <?php

    if(!empty($_POST["rep"])){
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'blog');
    $rep = $_POST["rep"];  

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT* FROM login WHERE name='$rep' ");
    if($result){
      $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      echo $data[4];
    }


    }
?>
```

Comment: thank you, that worked! But theres a huge space before the results. It looks like this:   "             email@email.com"

Comment: you can use trim  example - trim($data[4]);

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=m ysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM login  ");
```

change to this

```
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM login");
```

AND in get.php

```
if(isset($_POST["rep"]) && !empty($_POST["rep"])){
      $rep  = $_POST["rep"];
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'blog');


        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT* FROM login WHERE name='$rep' ");
        if($result){
          $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          echo $data[4];
        }


        }
```

Comment: html formatter did that, sorry. The code works if i manually type a user full name instead of the $rep variable